# Postman - How to assert that the array in the response body contains a string value in all its elements

Tags: arrays, postman, assert, assertion

New to Postman and not accustomed to writing code so please help. Couldn’t find any similar post either which I could use.
I want to add an assertion to check whether a value is present in all the elements in an array.

In the below example, I have an array Fee with 3 elements.
I want to pass the test when all of them have a ClientName which contains “Seville” in it. How could I do that?

```
{
“Fees”: [
{
“Id”: 1,
“clientName”: “Seville ABC”,
“ProductName”: “Product A”,
“Fee”: “123”,
},
{
“Id”: 2,
“clientName”: “Seville”,
“ProductName”: “Product A”,
“Fee”: “123”,
},
{
“Id”: 3,
“clientName”: “Seville XYZ”,
“ProductName”: “Product A”,
“Fee”: “123”,
}
]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
let jsonData = pm.response.json()

pm.test('The `clientName` contains Seville', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.Fee, (item) => {
        pm.expect(item.clientName).to.include('Seville')
    })
})
```

It's looping through the `Fee` array and then using the `.include` chai function the check if the `clientName` value, of each object, contains that string.

Comment: Yayyii! Thankyou so much! Worked just fine :)

Comment: Can you accept this as the answer to close out the question, please :)